# Tiktok API redirect URI with slash (/) leads to 404 in my case why?

Tags: slash, tiktok

After user clicks the login button and approved permission he redirect to this:

> https://...domain.../mytiktokapp/callback.php/?code=XXXXX&scopes=user.info.basic%2Cvideo.list&state=YYYYY

That lead to page 404 because the slash after callback.php

In the manage app setting the redirect URL to this:

> https://...domain.../mytiktokapp/callback.php/

I can't remove the slash <kbd>/</kbd> in the end - Added automatically after send my app to Tiktok review.
https://prnt.sc/MWbBBMpNqZAL

In address bar in the browser if remove the slash and click enter all done well.
The user info download according to my request for scopes user.info.basic, video.list

Trying contact Tiktok to remove the slash in the app setup redirect URI, but waiting them to answer.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem... Did you ever find a solution for this? Did TikTok support get back to you?

Comment: Hi, I haven't found a solution yet and am still waiting for Tiktok's response